# In Naruto Gaiden: The Seventh Hokage, who is this blue-haired guy sitting next to Boruto?

Tags: naruto, naruto-gaiden

In *Naruto Gaiden: The Seventh Hokage* manga, page 3

[image]

Who is the guy with blue hair sitting next to Boruto?

Is it a new character or did I miss something from Naruto?

Comment: he looks a lot like Gara and he is also boruto's friend so I believe he is Gara's son

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The character sitting next to Boruto is **Mitsuki**. He is a Konohagakure shinobi who originated from an unknown village and also the team-mate of Boruto and Sarada.

[image]

According to [Narutopedia](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Mitsuki):

> Born as Orochimaru's son, Mitsuki immigrated to Konohagakure, where he was then enrolled into the Konoha Academy. Most of Mitsuki's background is left as a complete mystery to the point where even his own team-mates don't know who his parents are.

Extract from [*Boruto: Naruto the movie*](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Mitsuki#Epilogue) summary:

> Boruto questions Mitsuki about his parentage, to which the latter says he is the son of Orochimaru. This shocks Sarada and she asks if Orochimaru is his mother or father while Boruto asks who Orochimaru is, and Mitsuki replies it doesn't matter, much to Boruto and Sarada's confusion.

Comment: Who are his parents? Which clan is he from ?  Possibly a Otsutsuki descendant?

Comment: but yes i also guessed that he might be Otsuzsuki because of the hair and the cloth of him. but yes still no details

Comment: Not sure if you want to change it, but he wasn't born in Konoha. Sarada doesn't even know him in the 2nd chapter of Naruto Gaiden

Comment: You might want to answer this also: http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/21377/who-are-mitsukis-parents?lq=1