# Who are Mitsuki's parents?

Tags: naruto-gaiden

From *Naruto Gaiden: The Seventh Hokage*, Chapter 2, Page 14.

I'm guessing one of them is Gaara. If so, who is he married to? Even when looking at the picture at the end of the chapter, I can't recall ever seeing that woman.

[image]

Comment: He has blue hair and white skin, nothing like gara.

Comment: He looks like Toneri to me and his name means "Full moon"

Comment: @AnkitSharma It isn't Toneri. Toneri has markings on his skin around his upper chest area while Mitsuki does not. They are two completely different people. The indications of Gaara being Mitsuki's parent is the same eyes and the picture at the very end of the chapter

Comment: As far i remember, Gaara doesn't have eye pupil.

Comment: @krikara gara and mitsuki have different eye. Not even close except the eye liner. Chest marking can be done later at-least.

Comment: @AnkitSharma Until someone can find out and prove who the parents are, we can't discount Gaara. Gaara's child doesn't have to look exactly like him.

Comment: Definitely not gaara's son because of eyebrows, hair color, eye pupil... Also if it would have been gaara's son he would have trained him at sand village... Too soon to say unless we see his Jutsu types or Kishimoto reveals the parents himself... If he has some sand technique he might be Gaara's son.. But too soon to say anything and live the discussion o assumptions..

Comment: @AbhishekShah True, if he was the Kazekage's son, you would expect him to be at the Sand village...

Comment: I think it might be Chōjūrō the current Mizukage. I mean he has the blue hair you know? And it said Mitsuki comes from another village.

Comment: Are the schools in Hidden Mist deserted?? @Austin

Comment: Hopefully not Sakata Gintoki. His hair somewhat looks like Sakata's. Joking..

Comment: Maybe Kabuto or Orochimaru son, maybe he´s a spy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has been revealed in *Boruto: Naruto the Movie* that, Mitsuki is Orochimaru's son.

Extract from the movie summary:

> Boruto questions Mitsuki about his parentage, to which the latter says he is the son of Orochimaru. This shocks Sarada and she asks if Orochimaru is his mother or father while Boruto asks who Orochimaru is, and Mitsuki replies it doesn't matter, much to Boruto and Sarada's confusion.
>
> <sub>source: [Mitsuki](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Mitsuki#Epilogue)</sub>

Comment: who is the mother?

Answer (score 1):

Mitsuki is Orochimaru's son. This was revealed in [Naruto Exhibition Official Guidebook "Michi"](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Michi).<sup>1</sup> Any other parentage is not known.

---

[1] Look at this [question](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/21316/11643).

Comment: Note that this particular part of the information is not revealed in that guidebook, as far as I can gather. It seems to come from spoiler to Boruto the Movie.

Comment: who is the mother?